# rake db:migrate is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

```
rake db:migrate
(in /home/pal/project/sprint-19)
DEPRECATION WARNING: require "activerecord" is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 3. Use require "active_record" instead. (called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/activerecord.rb:2)
DEPRECATION WARNING: "Rails.root/test/mocks/development" won't be added automatically to load paths anymore in future releases. (called from /home/pal/project/new-sprint/sprint-19/config/application.rb:51)
DEPRECATION WARNING: Rake tasks in /home/pal/project/new-sprint/sprint-19/vendor/plugins/authorization/tasks/authorization_tasks.rake are deprecated. Use lib/tasks instead. (called from /home/pa/project/new-sprint/sprint-19/Rakefile:7)
DEPRECATION WARNING: Rake tasks in /home/pal/project/new-sprint/sprint-19/vendor/plugins/chartdirector/tasks/chartdirector_tasks.rake are deprecated. Use lib/tasks instead. (called from /home/pal/project/new-sprint/sprint-19/Rakefile:7)
DEPRECATION WARNING: Rake tasks in /home/pal/project/new-sprint/sprint-19/vendor/plugins/headliner/tasks/headliner_tasks.rake are deprecated. Use lib/tasks instead. (called from /home/pal/project/new-sprint/sprint-19/Rakefile:7)
DEPRECATION WARNING: Rake tasks in /home/pal/project/new-sprint/sprint-19/vendor/plugins/open_flash_chart/tasks/open_flash_chart_tasks.rake are deprecated. Use lib/tasks instead. (called from /home/pal/project/new-sprint/sprint-19/Rakefile:7)
DEPRECATION WARNING: Rake tasks in /home/pal/project/new-sprint/sprint-19/vendor/plugins/rails_indexes/tasks/indexer.rake are deprecated. Use lib/tasks instead. (called from /home/pal/project/new-sprint/sprint-19/Rakefile:7)
DEPRECATION WARNING: RAILS_ROOT is deprecated. Please use ::Rails.root.to_s. (called from join at /home/pal/project/new-sprint/sprint-19/lib/tasks/helpers.rb:15)
rake aborted!
Table 'connect_production_new.settings' doesn't exist
```

I tried with both MySQL and Postgres but it's only throwing this error for MySQL.

Comment: Your migration is trying to do something with a table that does not exist yet. Please add your migrations to the question if you want a more detailed answer.

Comment: I have near arround 100 migration file and its my first migration means i created new database and now i am tring to do migration

Comment: Well, the error message is clear isn't it? `Table 'connect_production_new.settings' doesn't exist` This means one of your migrations is trying to use a table that does not exist yet. I don't think anyone can help you if you only post the error, but not your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you don't have the database or your schema is not updated, try to run `rake db:reset` (this will drop your DB, create the DB, load the schema and the seeds data, don't do this if you have important data in your DB).

See `bundle exec rake -T db` for more information.